# If the events $A_i$ are independent, then the probability that at least $k$ of them happen is less than $p^k/k!$

Tags: probability-theory, independence

> Consider $n$ independent events $A_1$, $A_2$, $\ldots$, $A_n$, let $P(A_k)=p_k$ and $p = p_1+p_2+\cdots p_n$, then the probability that at least $k$ of the events $A_1$, $A_2$, $\ldots$, $A_n$ happen is less than $p^k/k!$.

I have noticed that:

$$
\frac{p^k}{k!}>\sum p_{i_1}p_{i_2}\cdots p_{i_k}
$$
where $i_k\in\{1,2,\cdots n\}$ and $i_1<i_2<i_3\cdots<i_k$.

However I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: This is not true in general. Consider, for instance, what happens if all the events are the same. I therefore suggest that you add something like "the $A_i$ are all independent" to your question.

Comment: @Arthur You are right about it.

Comment: Then consider $$I(\omega)=\{i\mid1\leqslant i\leqslant n,\,\omega\in A_i\}$$ and note that $$[|I|\geqslant k]=\bigcup[\{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k\}\subset I]$$ where the union is over all the $k$tuples $(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k)$ such that $1\leqslant i_1<i_2<i_3\cdots<i_k\leqslant n$. The result follows since $$P(|I|\geqslant k)\leqslant\sum P(\{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k\}\subset I)=\sum p_{i_1}p_{i_2}\cdots p_{i_k}$$

Comment: @Did Can you translate your mathematical language to some more plain language, it is a bit too abstract to me. What is $I$, and why you last one inequality holds

Comment: @Did The problem for me is that I am not very familiar with the abstract notation.